# Using the format method, fill in the gaps in the convert_distance function so that it returns the phrase "X miles equals Y km", with Y having only 1

Tags: python

I get error here in the blank space. I do not understand what needed to be in those spaces to fill n get the proper result .

```
def convert_distance(miles):
    km = miles * 1.6 
    result = "{} miles equals {___} km".___  
    return result

print(convert_distance(12))
  #Should be: 12 miles equals 19.2 km
#what will be in the gaps to get those ans
```

Comment: Search for `string formatting in python`

Answer (score 2):

Here you just need to pass the miles and km in fixed format and as if needed 1 dec point we add .1f in second brackets

```
def convert_distance(miles):
    km = miles * 1.6 
    result = "{} miles equals {:.1f} km".format(miles,km)
    return result

print(convert_distance(12)) # Should be: 12 miles equals 19.2 km
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
result = "{miles} miles equals {km} km".format(miles=miles,km=km)

Answer (score 1):

you can also solve it this way. Using the format method. check the code snippet below.

```
def convert_distance(miles):
km = miles * 1.6 
result = "{miles} miles equals {km:.1f} km".format(miles=miles, km= miles * 1.6)
return result

print(convert_distance(12)) # Should print: 12 miles equals 19.2 km
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_distance(miles):
    km = miles * 1.6 
    result = "{} miles equals {:.2f} km".format(miles,km)
    return result

print(convert_distance(12)) # Should be: 12 miles equals 19.2 km
print(convert_distance(5.5)) # Should be: 5.5 miles equals 8.8 km
print(convert_distance(11)) # Should be: 11 miles equals 17.6 km
```